# What kind of professional should I speak to regarding protecting a house from auto defacto?

Tags: australia, contracts, common-law-marriage

I am currently building a house for myself. My partner is moving in with me; first into a rental property, then once the house is built we will move into the house together. I have read a lot of horror stories of assets being automatically acquired in the case that you and a partner automatically become defacto after a period of time. i.e. In a worst case, that they are entitled to half the build in the event of a breakup.

Looking to speak to someone (probably a law professional) to discuss what I can do to best protect myself in this scenario. I mean I view it as I love her, she loves me, and neither of us would do anything to hurt the other or try to take advantage. However I can't be certain that the version of her which "theoretically" no longer loved me would do. After so many years squirelling away funds, I am not prepared to risk my property.

What kind of professional should I speak to as to the best way to set this up to protect my asset?

Does anyone have any suggestions on what sort of terms and arrangements I can look into for this sort of scenario (surely it's not an uncommon thing)?

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you in? Laws for this kind of thing vary around the world.

Comment: Australia, NSW. I'm aware it varies, mostly after the information of "what to look for" :P

Answer (score 6):

You should talk with an attorney specializing in *family law*. The "defacto" status you are concerned about, where it exists, is called *common law marriage*. Protecting assets in the event of breakup of a marriage, whether standard (civil) or common law, may be addressed by a *prenuptial agreement*.

Comment: Sounds funny to have a prenup if you aren't planning on getting married. But if it actually helps to have one due to common laws, then wow, that's an eye opener that most people probably never even think of.

Comment: Also worth noting that a prenup, while useful, is not legally binding and the family court will take it into account along with other circumstances before making a determination. Because of this complexity, seeing a solicitor is essential!